# including controller files from external script in codeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, uploadify

I've the following directory structure.

```
application
| 
| -----> controller
            |
            | ------> profie_control.php
assets
|
| ------> Others 
             |
             |---> uploadify 
                     |
                     | --> uploadify.php
```

Now in my `uploadify.php` I am doing all the stuff that I want to perform.Then after everything is done I want to call a function and pass data to it in `profile_control.php`.Now I dont know how to access the functions.
I tried to use the following code

```
include_once("http://localhost/php/ci/index.php/profile_control/myfunction");
```

in `uploadify.php` but it gives me the following error

```
Warning: include_once() [function.include-once]: http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0 in C:\wamp\www\php\ci\assets\Others\uploadify\uploadify.php on line 8
```

And I've read in some forums that this approach is not good as it can cause security issues.Now how I can send data from `uploadify.php` to `profile_control.php` securely or what would be a better alternative ???

Answer (score 0):

You can't include/require by URL, but you can include/require by path, and it's what you want to do. In your controller:

```
include_once("../../assets/Others/uploadify/uploadify.php");
some_func(); // function from file 'uploadify.php'
```

Comment: is it secure enough to do it like this ?

Comment: Yes, there is no better way to do this. It's better to `require_once` instead of `include_once` though, but that's a different story.

Comment: i tried your suggestion but it is giving me error.It is saying that it cannot find the `CI_Controller` of codeIgniter which I've inherited in profile_control class.